# Negative CSS hover link

Tags: html, css

So I am going to be very simple and easy here, but something is not working and i don't know why and how to change it.

I'm trying to make a dark field that can light up with a lot of divs in a div field

So i have 9 Div's like this:

```
-----------------

#Div1 #Div2 #Div3
#Div4 #Div5 #Div6
#Div7 #Div8 #Div9

-----------------
```

**When I hover over `#Div1`**

Make `#Div2` and `#Div4` = `75% visible`

`#Div3`, `#Div5` and `#Div7` = `50% visible`.

and lastly `#Div6` and `#Div8` = `25% visible`.

`#Div 9` cannot be seen from `#Div1`

The problem is when I try to hover over `#Div2`.

The same pattern would be applied, but `#Div1` is not showing up.

## What causes this and how can i fix this?

Thanks in advance :)

Here is how CSS looks:

```css
#container { width: 250px;}
#container div {margin: 1px;}

#puzzelpiece1   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece2   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece3   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece4   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece5   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece6   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece7   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece8   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece9   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }



#puzzelpiece1:hover { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0); }
#puzzelpiece1:hover ~ #puzzelpiece2 { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.25); }
#puzzelpiece1:hover ~ #puzzelpiece3 { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.50); }
#puzzelpiece1:hover ~ #puzzelpiece4 { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.25); }
#puzzelpiece1:hover ~ #puzzelpiece5 { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.50); }
#puzzelpiece1:hover ~ #puzzelpiece6 { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.75); }
#puzzelpiece1:hover ~ #puzzelpiece7 { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.50); }
#puzzelpiece1:hover ~ #puzzelpiece8 { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.75); }
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id="puzzelpiece1"></div>
  <div id="puzzelpiece2"></div>
  <div id="puzzelpiece3"></div>
  <div id="puzzelpiece4"></div>
  <div id="puzzelpiece5"></div>
  <div id="puzzelpiece6"></div>
  <div id="puzzelpiece7"></div>
  <div id="puzzelpiece8"></div>
  <div id="puzzelpiece9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to achieve this full CSS or some JS/jQuery can be involve?

Comment: This can easily be solved with a tiny help from JavaScript.

Comment: @MLG_No_Scope did any of the answers here help you? If so please consider marking one as the right answer or provide more context to your problem.

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Comment: yeah, i found the problem, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the documentation for `~`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators). It is the **subsequent-sibling combinator**.

> The subsequent-sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~) character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the document tree and the element represented by the first sequence **precedes** (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the second one.

`#Div2` does not precede `#Div1`.

---

CSS has no mechanism to style an element based on the state of a subsequent element.

You need to use JavaScript for this.

e.g. use a `mouseover` event to add a class to the element which contains the divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't go backwards, however you can go forwards and use nth-child on a nested level like so. Please keep in mind you should definitely combine some CSS properties for maintainability. I've just copy pasted them down for the sake of simplicity building this.

**Edit:** Yes I'm ashamed of this solution and wouldn't ever use it, this should realistically be solved with some simple JS, but this shows it's POSSIBLE in CSS only.

```css
.wrap { max-width: 240px; }

#puzzelpiece1   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece2   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece3   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece4   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece5   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece6   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece7   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece8   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece9   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: black; float: left; }

#puzzelpiece1-overlay   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: transparent; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece2-overlay   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: transparent; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece3-overlay   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: transparent; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece4-overlay   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: transparent; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece5-overlay   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: transparent; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece6-overlay   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: transparent; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece7-overlay   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: transparent; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece8-overlay   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: transparent; float: left; }
#puzzelpiece9-overlay   { width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: transparent; float: left; }


#puzzelpiece1-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(1) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0); }
#puzzelpiece1-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(2) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.25); }
#puzzelpiece1-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(3) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.50); }
#puzzelpiece1-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(4) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.25); }
#puzzelpiece1-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(5) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.50); }
#puzzelpiece1-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(6) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.75); }
#puzzelpiece1-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(7) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.50); }
#puzzelpiece1-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(8) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.75); }

#puzzelpiece2-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(1) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.25); }
#puzzelpiece2-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(2) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.0); }
#puzzelpiece2-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(3) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.25); }
#puzzelpiece2-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(4) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.50); }
#puzzelpiece2-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(5) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.25); }
#puzzelpiece2-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(6) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.50); }
#puzzelpiece2-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(7) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.75); }
#puzzelpiece2-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(8) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.50); }
#puzzelpiece2-overlay:hover ~ #visual div:nth-child(9) { background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.75); }

#stage {
    position: relative;
}

#visual {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="stage">
        <div id="puzzelpiece1-overlay"></div>
        <div id="puzzelpiece2-overlay"></div>
        <div id="puzzelpiece3-overlay"></div>
        <div id="puzzelpiece4-overlay"></div>
        <div id="puzzelpiece5-overlay"></div>
        <div id="puzzelpiece6-overlay"></div>
        <div id="puzzelpiece7-overlay"></div>
        <div id="puzzelpiece8-overlay"></div>
        <div id="puzzelpiece9-overlay"></div>

        <div id="visual">
            <div id="puzzelpiece1"></div>
            <div id="puzzelpiece2"></div>
            <div id="puzzelpiece3"></div>
            <div id="puzzelpiece4"></div>
            <div id="puzzelpiece5"></div>
            <div id="puzzelpiece6"></div>
            <div id="puzzelpiece7"></div>
            <div id="puzzelpiece8"></div>
            <div id="puzzelpiece9"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```